# Groupby pandas rows based on threshold of string differences

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, compare, row

I want to group my rows by how many values they have in common up to a certain threshold. For instance:

```
d = {'genomes':['g1','g2','g3','g4'], 'gene1':['A','B','B','A'], 'gene2':['A','A','A','A'],'gene3':['A','A','A','A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
gb = df.groupby(list(df.columns[1:]))
for key, item in gb:
    print(gb.get_group(key))
```

Will group rows based on those with no differences:

|  | genomes | gene1 | gene2 | gene3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | g1 | A | A | A |
| 3 | g4 | A | A | A |

|  | genomes | gene1 | gene2 | gene3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | g2 | B | A | A |
| 2 | g3 | B | A | A |

Is it possible to do something similar for those with <=1, <=5 differences etc.?

Edit: The output can be a list of lists of the 'genomes' columns, so in the example above [['g1','g4'],['g2',g3']]
Additionally, set comparisons would be appropriate because there won't actually be duplicate values in a row

Comment: Note: instead of `print(gb.get_group(key))` you can just do `print(item)`

Comment: So what are you expecting to be printed? Will you please give a sample in the question?

Comment: In the example I formatted the printed output into a table just so it was clear. Such as:

  genomes gene1 gene2 gene3
0      g1     A     A     A
3      g4     A     A     A
  genomes gene1 gene2 gene3
1      g2     B     A     A
2      g3     B     A     A

But this could just as well be a list of lists of the genomeIDs

Comment: No, you can't easily. Also would it make sense? Imagine you have 100 columns, 100 rows, each row has one difference with the previous, after 100 changes the 100th row is completely different from the 1st, but by continuity they would be in the same group.

Comment: That would actually be fine, to generate single-linkage clusters. I know that in the data I'm working with you don't get such diverse clusters as that. It'll be a minority of the rows linked by these single differences